# Horizontally scroll UITextField in a UITableViewCell if text overflows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uitextfield

How would I be able to horizontally scroll a UITextField in a UITableViewCell if the text overflows? I want it so that the user can scroll the text to see all of it, but it should not interfere with the swipe left to delete gesture in a UITableView. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should be happening automatically, but the hit regions are very small. This will likely lead to user confusion since two gestures in very small areas do two different things.

Are you sure that's a `UITextField` you're using in the cell? Looks like it's a `UILabel` because of the truncation.

Comment: This is after the keyboard dismisses. I want it so that when the user types in text that goes off the screen they can scroll through it.